# What kind of bug is this & does it eat aphids?

Tags: identification, pest-control, bugs

I want to get rid of aphids in my garden in a non-chemical way. I know that certain bugs can help a lot by eating aphids.

One such example are ladybugs, but unfortunately I can't find big populations of them.

However, I have heard that this bug also eats aphids:
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Does any one know its name and whether it eats aphids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug is newly arrived in the United States, [firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug). Native to Europe they eat seeds there.  As they are new in North America their behaviour could change but it is likely they do not eat aphids. See the [Utah State University extension fact sheet](http://extension.usu.edu/files/publications/factsheet/red-fire-bug08.pdf) for more information.

They are not hazardous to people. There have been reports of them eating other insects in North America but I would not rely on them to eat aphids.